# Why is one of the queries returning no rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 queries like this:

Query #1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Products 
WHERE CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) IN ('6', '8', '9', '10', '12', '14', '110', '106')
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Products 
WHERE CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) IN (SELECT ('6'', ''8'', ''9'', ''10'', ''12'', ''14'', ''110'', ''106'))
```

Why does the second query return no rows? When 1st query is returning some rows.

Comment: Exactly what are you *trying* to achieve when you put `''` where you previously had `'`?

Answer (score 2):

You have way too many single quotes in your query #2...

Also: if `ID` is a numeric column - why not just use

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Products 
WHERE ID IN (6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 110, 106)
```

Much easier, not unnecessary `CAST` involved .....

Also: if you ever really do need a `CAST` - I would recommend to **always** define a **length** for your `VARCHAR` ! Otherwise, you might end up with truncated strings....

So use:   `CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(100))` instead of just  `CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)`

Comment: Actually i have a slightly different requirement. I have a column named ID which is varchar(100) say. I need to compare it basd on the value of a parameter say something like this...

A.ID IN (CASE WHEN #ID = 1 THEN '1,1,3,4,5,6' WHEN #ID = 2 THEN '5,6' ELSE '0')

Comment: i was trying to make it simple to understand that is why

Comment: @Ashish: you made it **too simple** and thus any solution we present will not really be helpful to you.... don't **oversimplify** ....

Comment: is there any solution to this problem..?

Comment: @Ashish: I suggest you ask the question again - with the **real** issue at hand - then someone might be able to help ....

Answer (score 0):

The second query considers the values as a single string

You have to use '' (single quotes) to seperate character values when used in a **IN clause**

Comment: Thanks for quick reply ..Now how i will make it to treat as comma separated string?

Comment: you have to try some thing like this  declare @str varchar(200)='6,8,9';
    exec('SELECT  * FROM dbo.Products WHERE CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) in ('+@str +')')

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the second query return no rows? When 1st query is returning
> some rows.

Because the values returned by the `SELECT` statement in the `IN` predicate in the second query [**returns *only* one string value**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82257) which is:

```
6','8','9','10','12','14','110','106
```

So you will end up comparing the casted int ID value with only one string value `6','8','9','10','12','14','110','106'` so your query sill be evaluated like so

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Products 
WHERE CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)  = ''6','8','9','10','12','14','110','106'';
```

But there are distinct string values inside the `IN` clause in the first query:

```
6   8   9   10  12  14  110 106
```

However, you didn't need to cast it to varchar at all:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Products 
WHERE ID IN (6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 110, 106)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second query is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Products 
WHERE CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) IN ('6'', ''8'', ''9'', ''10'', ''12'', ''14'', ''110'', ''106')
```

or even this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Products 
WHERE CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) = '6'', ''8'', ''9'', ''10'', ''12'', ''14'', ''110'', ''106'
```

So, it returns no rows because you have no row with the ID `6', '8', '9', '10', '12', '14', '110', '106`